# Bootstrap navbar-expand-md height increasing @768px - 992px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm having a slight problem with the navbar-expand-md. From 768px to 992px the navbar height increases and the navbar-brand gets pushed a little down. It's a minor issue, but it's really bugging me and I can't seem to solve this problem. My skills are not to proficient so I'm at the end of my wit and would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance - happy holidays, stay healthy.

The issue described above can be seen here:

https://jsfiddle.net/w3do6z74/

Navbar-code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">brandname</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"><img src="imgs/category_bar_history.png" class="category-bar">History</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"><img src="imgs/category_bar_nature.png" class="category-bar">Nature</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"><img src="imgs/category_bar_travel.png" class="category-bar">Travel & Food</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"><img src="imgs/category_bar_arts.png" class="category-bar">Arts</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"><img src="imgs/category_bar_science.png" class="category-bar">Science</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"><img src="imgs/category_bar_crime.png" class="category-bar">Crime</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link nav-custom-link" href="#">HYPE</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Custom-Css:

```
.nav-custom-link {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}

.navbar {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-family: 'Audiowide', cursive;
}

.category-bar {
  padding-right: 4px;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  padding: 0.2rem 0.55rem;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
 }

.navbar-toggler:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the CSS in dev tools, you can see that one of the things changing on the `ul` element is the bottom margin. It's 0.5rem by default and 0 if the minimum width is larger than 992px:

```css
@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.mb-2 {
  margin-bottom: .5rem!important;
}
```

```css
@media (min-width: 992px)
.mb-lg-0 {
  margin-bottom: 0!important;
}
```

It's because you added `mb-2` and `mb-lg-0` classes to your `ul` element:

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0"></ul>
```

To fix this, you can add `mb-0` and remove `mb-lg-0`:

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-0"></ul>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking time out of your day to help. This works like a charm. Thanks again!